# WIX enable Windows feature

Tags: wix, wix3.7, wix-extension, dism

I have to check if some windows features are enabled beore installing my software.

I can check it or install it using dism command line tool.

I create a custom action to do this, but is there a way to do it in a "WIX native way" ?

```
<Property Id="dism" Value="dism.exe" />
<CustomAction Id="InstallMSMQContainer" Property="dism" ExeCommand=" /online /enable-feature /featurename:MSMQ-Container /featurename:MSMQ-Server /featurename:MSMQ-ADIntegration" Return="check" Impersonate="yes"  Execute="oncePerProcess"/>

<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="InstallMSMQContainer" After="CostFinalize" Overridable="yes">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
```

The problem is that command launch a command prompt, which is very ugly for end user.
How can I make it nicer? I don't know if i need a bootstraper to do this (like installing the .NET Framework).

Is there any extention to manage that things ?

I'm now using WIX 3.7.

Comment: Take a look at quiet execution custom action: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm

Comment: @YanSklyarenko just noticed your comment after posting an answer with same link!

Answer (score 6):

David Gardiner's answer hinted at the correct solution in my case. Creating your own custom action is not necessary. Here is how to do it for a 64 bit installation of Windows:

First determine if MSMQ is installed:

```
<Property Id="MSMQINSTALLED">
  <RegistrySearch Id="MSMQVersion" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters" Type="raw" Name="CurrentBuild" />
</Property>
```

Declare your custom actions. You need two. One to set a property to the path to dism, and another to execute it:

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallMsmq_Set" Property="InstallMsmq" Value="&quot;[System64Folder]dism.exe&quot; /online /enable-feature /featurename:msmq-server /all" Execute="immediate"/>
<CustomAction Id="InstallMsmq" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check"/>
```

Finally specify the custom actions in the install sequence:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="InstallMsmq_Set" After="CostFinalize"/>
  <Custom Action="InstallMsmq" After="InstallInitialize">NOT REMOVE AND NOT MSMQINSTALLED</Custom> 
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Because this can take a little bit of time I've added the following to update the installer status text:

```
<UI> 
  <ProgressText Action="InstallMsmq">Installing MSMQ</ProgressText> 
</UI>
```

You can also specify a rollback action if you want to remove MSMQ on installation failure.

Comment: For those looking at installing a different windows feature, I found the above helpful, and this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992363/test-for-windows-features#answer-18997675

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the [Quiet Execution Custom Action](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html)

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is by creating a DTF custom action that calls the dism.exe process. You get the same result and no command prompt is launched.

```cs
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult RunDism(Session session)
{
    session.Log("Begin RunDism");
    string arguments = session["CustomActionData"];

    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = "dism.exe";
        session.Log("DEBUG: Trying to run {0}", info.FileName);
        info.Arguments = arguments;
        session.Log("DEBUG: Passing the following parameters: {0}", info.Arguments);
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process deployProcess = new Process();
        deployProcess.StartInfo = info;

        deployProcess.Start();
        StreamReader outputReader = deployProcess.StandardOutput;
        deployProcess.WaitForExit();
        if (deployProcess.HasExited)
        {
            string output = outputReader.ReadToEnd();
            session.Log(output);
        }
        if (deployProcess.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            session.Log("ERROR: Exit code is {0}", deployProcess.ExitCode);
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        session.Log("ERROR: An error occurred when trying to start the process.");
        session.Log(ex.ToString());
        return ActionResult.Failure;
    }
    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

DISM parameters are set via the custom action data.