# Test for Windows Features

Tags: wix

I have an installer that runs a CustomAction which runs an embedded powershell script to test for the installed status of various required windows features.  This works correctly but it is terribly slow to complete.

Is there an alternative method to test for such features?  I expect there to be something along the lines of registry keys for each feature and sub-feature but I have not found any documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a (now deleted) suggestion to use a managed DTF custom action to query for server features in C#.

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult CheckFeatures(Session session)
{
    SelectQuery q = new SelectQuery("Win32_ServerFeature");
    ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(q);
    foreach (ManagementObject e in s.Get())
    {
        if((UInt32)e["ID"] == FeatureId)
        {
            session["FeatureIsSet"] = "1";
        }
    }
}

<CustomAction Id="CACheck" BinaryKey="CA" DllEntry="CheckFeatures" 
Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
<Binary Id="CA" SourceFile="path/to/bin" />
```

Answer (score 4):

In one of the installation projects we used [dism.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744566%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to enable required Windows features.

For example, enabling ASP.NET in IIS 8 was done with the following custom action:

```
<!-- 32-bit edition of Windows knows where to find dism.exe -->
<Property Id="DISMEXEPATH" Value="dism.exe" />

<!-- 64-bit edition of Windows requires this workaround to get proper dism.exe version -->
<SetProperty Id="DISMEXEPATH" Value="[WindowsFolder]Sysnative\dism.exe" After="AppSearch">VersionNT64</SetProperty>

<!-- And the CA to do the job (with the help of [quiet execution CA][2]) -->
<CustomAction Id="SetForEnableAspNetIIS8" Property="EnableAspNetIIS8" Value="&quot;[DISMEXEPATH]&quot; /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /featurename:IIS-NetFxExtensibility45 /featurename:NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45 /featurename:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /featurename:IIS-ISAPIFilter" />
<CustomAction Id="EnableAspNetIIS8" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check"/>
```

This doesn't seem to be a good practice, but it worked for that project.

Comment: This is good but it would not work without elevated permissions.

Comment: @tmutton Installers normally run with elevated permissions

Comment: @JamesBarrass Not always automatically. Instances where the user is not logged on with an Administrator account is one instance. Windows will usually prompt you before running.

Comment: You need to run dism.exe as an admin anyways, so elevated permissions are required