# How to automatically turn on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

please I have an application that needs IIS to run, now IIS needs to be turned on manually in the windows control panel. But I want to avoid this process and automatically turn on IIS how can I do this. Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about turning on the IIS Windows Feature? Is that the control panel you're referring to? If not, which one? And what's your "entry point" for trying to do this? Some form of installer package? (If so, what technology are you using to build it?)

Comment: Yes I mean turning on the IIs windows feature in the control panel. I am trying to do it from an installer package. I am using the dot net frame work to build it.

Comment: By tech, I meant visual studio setup project, Wix, InstallShield, etc. What are you authoring the *setup* project in?

Comment: Ok I am using Wix.

Comment: Similar question wanting to [install MSMQ via WIX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18126502/15498). The specific package will change for IIS but the general technique should apply.

Answer (score 0):

The IIS is implemented as a Windows Service. So the only thing necessary is you to make sure the `Startup type` of the W3SVC is set to `Automatic`. It is set to automatic by default, so your question implies that someone has changed it to one of the other options.

So open the services and look for `World Wide Web Publishing Service`. Then double-click on it and you'll be present with its properties. From the `Startup type` drop-down choose `Automatic`. Restart your computer. The IIS will start automatically.

## UPDATE

Based on the OP's comment I assume the re-configuration of the service is necessary.

Unfortunately, there is no managed class to change the service startup type. You can go through P/Invoke and call the native Windows API. Another option is to utilize the WMI. But the quickest way is to spawn a privileged `cmd.exe` from your application installer and run the following:

```
sc config w3svc start=auto
```

However, this is not a bulletproof solution as someone else might later change it again to `demand` or even `disabled`.

If you're looking for a mechanism to start the service at the execution of the application installer, you might want the `ServiceController` class. It can start the service but it cannot change its startup type. Here is the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx).

So you could do something like this in your code:

```
using (var w3cvs = new ServiceController("W3Svc"))
{
    if (w3cvs.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
    {
        w3cvs.Start();                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Since Automatic is the default start mode for this service after IIS is installed, I'm struggling to work out if this is what the OP means, or if as in my comments they're talking about *installing* IIS, or something else.

Comment: From the different divices tested on, iis service was turned off. So I am looking for a way to turn it on through the application installer package. Without going into WWW publishing services